# How to get "Non-Root" access on Emulators ?

Tags: adb, genymotion

I am running adb on emulators and by default, the emulators give root access. 
When I execute 'adb shell', I get root access to the emulator(virtual device).

For some reason, I want to have non-root access to emulators. What shall I do ?

Any help would be appreciated.

### *Configurations

Ubuntu 13.10, 32-bit.

Eclipse 4.2 with ADT bundle.

Genymotion Emulator(To be specific, I was using Android 4.3 here).

Comment: You could try `su shell` to become the "shell user". That's the one `adb shell` normally uses on devices. But I'm not sure if it is available on the emulator, so please let us know if it works. If the `shell` user is not available, you could check `ls -l /data/data` to pick the user of some app to try with.

Comment: @Izzy - 'su shell' does not work with emulators. 
I am working on this issue and hopefully very near to solution. Will definitely let you know as it is done.

Answer (score 4):

On the SDK emulators and virtual machines like Genymotion, `adbd` starts up as root and provides a root shell. Short of modifying the source code to do otherwise and rebuilding your VM images, I think you will have to use the `su` approach suggested above. `su shell` does indeed work on both SDK emulators as well as the Genymotion VMs. Specifically:

```
ubuntu$ adb shell
android# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) context=u:r:shell:s0
android# su shell
android$ uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) context=u:r:su:s0
```

Note that the initial shell is running as uid 0 and after `su shell` is running as uid 2000. In fact, you can su to any Linux uid (Android `userId`+`appId`) configured on your emulator/VM.  For example, after doing `adb shell` from Ubuntu:

```
android# su u0_a16
android$ id
uid=10016(u0_a16) gid=10016(u0_a16) context=u:r:su:s0
android$
```

On my emulator, uid 0010016 is the calendar app for user 0 (owner, `userId` 00). Remember that after you su, you only have the privileges of the new uid, and this may not include permissions to run Linux commands or view certain directories.

Finally, if you just need to do one or two operations as the non-root user, you can string the whole thing together as one command in Ubuntu. Something like:

```
ubuntu$ adb shell su u0_a16 id
uid=10016(u0_a16) gid=10016(u0_a16) context=u:r:su:s0
```

or

```
ubuntu$ adb shell su radio cat /data/data/com.android.phone/shared_prefs/*.xml\; su radio id
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <boolean name="_has_set_default_values" value="true" />
</map>
uid=1001(radio) gid=1001(radio) context=u:r:su:s0
```

Above tested on SDK x86 emulator running 4.4.2 and Genymotion VM running 4.4.2.